What could cause model trainings to have big random loss spikes?
I am currently training a DeepLabv3 variant with EfficientNet as a backbone for semantic segmentation, on tf 2.16.1 with an RTX 4090. On some training instances, at a single random epoch (never the same but often around the 40th), I get a big spike in training loss (SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy), creating an even bigger spike in validation loss. It disappears a few epochs later without seemingly impacting much the rest of the training.
See example: Training Loss Training IoU Validation Loss Validation IoU.
I get these spikes 80% of the times I try to train the model locally on the 4090. Does anyone have an idea where it can come from?
I tried using different backbones (EffNet B1 to B7, Resnet) for the encoder and I tried different batch sizes from 8 to 32, but the spikes will happen almost all of the time with the 4090.
I tried training on Collab with the T4 GPU a few times and never got any spikes, but very similar end results for the model, which means the spikes don't really impact the performances.

It sounds like you're encountering sporadic spikes in training loss during the training of your semantic segmentation model using DeepLabv3 with EfficientNet as a backbone on TensorFlow 2.16.1, particularly when using an RTX 4090 GPU. Here are a few potential reasons and solutions.Check GPU memory usage during training using tools like nvidia-smi or TensorFlow's GPU profiler (tf.profiler). Ensure that memory consumption is within acceptable limits throughout training epochs.

TensorFlow can be affected by randomness in data shuffling and random seed initialization, which might lead to occasional spikes in loss at certain epochs. Solution: Set random seeds for TensorFlow operations and NumPy to ensure reproducibility between training runs. This might help in stabilizing the training process and reduce the occurrence of these spikes.
Ensure that data shuffling is consistent between training runs by controlling the seed or shuffling strategy.
